# Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{16n^2-(4j-2)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

It looks like Riemann's sum, if:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{n} 4n\sqrt{1-\frac{(4j-2)^2}{16n^2}}$$
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j-2}{4n}\right)^2}$$

..but it doesn't fit to formula
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} f\left(a+j\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$

I tried something like $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, cuz it came at first, but it is integrable when $x\in[-1,1]$ which doesn't help me, when i think about proper a and b in this case. Should I need to renumber sum index? Or start from completely other step? I'm not acquainted with other theorems to solve problems like this

Comment: You might be able to use the squeeze theorem with two of these Riemann limits using the fact that $4j \geq 4j - 2 \geq 4j - 4 = 4(j - 1)$. You do need to take care of the first few terms a bit differently I guess.

Comment: Can't you just see it as a generalized Riemann sum with $x_j^* = \frac{4j-2}{4n}$?  (Here $x_j^*$ is in the interval $[\frac{j-1}{n}, \frac{j}{n}]$ so it's just using the midpoints of the intervals of a uniform partition.)

Answer (score 2):

You have, using that $(4j)^2 \geq (4j - 2)^2 \geq (4j - 4)^2 = (4(j-1))^2$ for $j \geq 1$, and that $2^2 \geq 2^2 \geq 0$ for $j = 0$:
$$\frac{1}{n}\!\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{n}} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)^2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}\!\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j-2}{4n}\right)^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}\!\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^2}$$
The LHS and the RHS both tend to $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2}\mathrm{d}x$, hence by the squeeze theorem the middle expression converges to that limit too, which is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$ by performing the substitution $x = \sin(u)$, $\mathrm{d}x = \cos(u)\mathrm{d}u$.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the continuous case
$$I_n=\frac{1}{4n^2}\int_{0}^{n} \sqrt{16n^2-(4j-2)^2}\,dj$$
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{4 n^2-1}+(2n-1)\sqrt{4 n-1} }{8 n^2}+\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 n^2-1}+\sqrt{4 n-1}}{2 n}\right)$$ Expanded as a series for large $n$
$$I_n=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{3 n^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\right)$$

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula
$$ \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{16n^2-(4j-2)^2}=\frac \pi 4 \left(1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}+\cdots  \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j}{4n}\right)^2}<
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j-2}{4n}\right)^2}<
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j-4}{4n}\right)^2}
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)^2}<
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4j-2}{4n}\right)^2}<
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^2}
$$
Both left and right sums tend to $\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=\pi/4$.

Comment: A distinction needs to be made for $j = 0$, since we do not have $\sqrt{1 - 0} \leq \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{n^2}}$, and once the disctinction is made this answer is pretty much mine... Though I could be wrong.